# Convert PDF to CMYK but ignore black?

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, cmyk

I am converting an RGB PDF to CMYK using the following command:

```
/usr/local/bin/gs -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOCACHE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \ 
-sColorConversionStrategy=CMYK -sColorConversionStrategyForImages=CMYK \
-dProcessColorModel=/DeviceCMYK -dEncodeColorImages=false \
-dEncodeGrayImages=false -dEncodeMonoImages=false -sOutputFile=CMYK.PDF RGB.PDF
```

The resulting file is 100% CMYK, however anything that was 100% black in the RGB PDF is now:

```
C: 72%
M: 68%
Y: 67%
K: 89%
```

The result is that black is a slightly dark grey when really it should be black.

Is there anything I need to add to this command to ensure black remains as black during the conversion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the current version of pdfwrite you are restricted to the colour conversions in the software, and there is nothign you can do about this.

The colour management is undergoing *serious* revision, and the next release should make it possible to deal with this.

Comment: Sadly, 5 years later, this still [seem to be not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56490703/1032586).

Comment: I believe this is indeed possible now, but you will need to write your own RGB ICC profile. The RGB and CMYK profiles supplied with Ghostscript won't do it. Which I believe was the answer we gave on our IRC channel (though possibly to someone else).

Comment: Well... maybe. But I've never seen any working example. The only approach that seem to be somewhat close is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35646895/1032586) collink-based one. Sadly, it [doesn't work for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35596346/ghostscript-convert-pdf-into-cmyk-preserving-pure-black-for-text#comment100970828_35646895) too.

Answer (score 0):

## Examples of Ghostscript commands to convert PDF from sRGB or eciRGB_v2 to eciCMYK_v2 (FOGRA 59) while keeping black plain (K only), not rich (CMYK)

I managed to convert PDF file in RGB to CMYK while keeping RGB black #000000 plain K black, not rich CMYK black.

DeviceLink ICC had to be created from e.g. eciRGB_v2 (or sRGB, if your source is sRGB) profile to the appropriate CMYK profile using collink tool (from argyll package) with the "-f" attribute to hack the black colors.

Ghostscript is then called with a control file declaring use of the profile and its parameters.

### Example of making the DeviceLink RGB to CMYK profile

```
collink -v -f eciRGB_v2.icc eciCMYK_v2.icc eciRGB_v2_to_eciCMYK_v2.icc
```

### Example of a control file to map eciRGB_v2 to eciCMYK_v2

```
Image_RGB   eciRGB_v2_to_eciCMYK_v2.icc 0   1   0
Graphic_RGB eciRGB_v2_to_eciCMYK_v2.icc 0   1   0
Text_RGB    eciRGB_v2_to_eciCMYK_v2.icc 0   1   0
```

### Sample ghostscript command to do the actual conversion

```
gs -o 2-output-cmyk-from-eciRGB.pdf \
       -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
       -sColorConversionStrategy=CMYK \
       -sSourceObjectICC=control-eciRGB_v2.txt \
       1-input-rgb.pdf
```